# How to select a column names of a table in mysql based on the value it contains

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table with name **test**. it got 7 columns **id , a , b , c , d , e , f.** All this columns contains either 1 or 0. Now i want make a query where i can choose only those columns whose value is 1.

Something like this:

```
select (condition) from test where id = 5;
```

because i have a hotel table with 50 columns out of which 11 columns contains either 1 or 0 representing the facilities of the hotel. I want to make a query which just tells what are the facilities of the hotel.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't think you've quite grasped how you should really use database queries.

Comment: I know using sql queries we can just select rows but i want to know can we do that even for columns or how people do that in real time scenarios...

Comment: Because it returns a data set - that set wouldn't be structurally normal if you had a random set of columns for each row

Comment: can you be bit clear about that..

Comment: Well, a result set from a database is meant to be a defined set of columns, and the data within them for each row. If the columns are different for each row, then it's not a result set, it's just a load of random data. It has no structure, and would be difficult to work with or predict it's behaviour. It'd be no different to doing a single select with different columns for each row in the database. You're meant to work with the data, not the columns

Comment: Put simply, imagine a spreadsheet where the column only exists in some cases depending on the data... It's impossible - the same goes for a database result set.

Comment: so is there any effective way to handle above suitivations ...

Comment: thanks for the valuable information....cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select id, (a*64)+(b*32)+(c*16)+(d*8)+(e*4)+(f*2)+(g*1)
from test

this number you can reverse it to convert to a 7 digit binary code.

examples:
18 = 0010010 , 1000000 = 64

Comment: i guess its a smart way ... but i dont have any column named  (a*64)+(b*32)+(c*16)+(d*8)+(e*4)+(f*2)+(g*1).. or if i m wrong please be more bit clear

Comment: no problem, use the name of your columns. if it has a value of 1 it will multiply and aggregate. you can use your 50 columns just keep doubling the multiplicity. you'll need to parse/convert in your application with a method/function.

Comment: you could also concatenate strings with the hardcoded column name if the value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

using sql you can select rows, NOT columns

If it is that what you want you can bulid your query like this

```
select id, a, b, c, d -- columns to select
from test  -- table
where (a = 1 or b=1 or c = 1 or d = 1) -- these are the conditions
```